# Two different answer for the same Http GET request

Tags: android, retrofit

i send the same GET request one time from Curl and the other from an android application ,but the server responds with 2 different answers.From the curl the response is HTTP 200 ok, with Android the response is 401 unauthorized access . the problem may be in authentication token.I use Retrofit for HttpConnection

Curl Request:

```
HEADERS

Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
Host: requestb.in
Via: 1.1 vegur
Connection: close
Connect-Time: 2 
Total-Route-Time: 1 
X-Instructor-Token: VAmfAkkpLPq4PKeGhpaY
X-Instructor-Email: b@a.com
X-Request-Id: de7b9a62-abed-488d-afb5-414f9548ebc5
```

Android Request:

```
HEADERS 

Content-Type:application/json 
Accept-Encoding: gzip 
Accept: applicationjson 
User-Agent: Dalvik/1.6.0(Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; SM-N900 Build/KOT49H) 
Host: requestb.in 
Via: 1.1 vegur
Connection: close 
Connect-Time: 11
Total-Route-Time: 19
X-Instructor-Token: VAmfAkkpLPq4PKeGhpaY
X-Instrutor-Email: b@a.com
X-Request-Id: 7b45ac68-54f8-49b3-baf4-bef41d661332
```

Comment: You can RTFM of curl and have it post the same request as Android does.  It must be the same answer. After that, you will be able to find out which header causes the response.

Comment: Connect-Time: 11 Accept: ***applicationjson*** -- no slash. Backslash in Win sources?

Comment: i post the same request but the server responds with different answers

Comment: can you direct both via the same proxy? (e.g. burp)

Comment: the User-Agent is different, and, as @18446744073709551615 pointed out, the `Accept` header in android is wrong. also the android request has a few extra header.

Comment: @njzk2 the user agent must be different because the request is from 2 different clients, i corrected the missing slash in the android and the same wrong response is returned

Comment: @HaithamKhedr: the user-agent is what you want it to be (like all headers, btw). it is entirely possible that your server refuses to answer to an android phone.

Comment: @njzk2 i tried another POST request and it worked fine ,this GET request is the one failing

Comment: user-agent and accept-encoding seem to be the only 2 difference. I suggest you change those in your curl request to see if that fails.

Comment: tried ,didn't work either

Comment: I remember once I had to set User-Agent to Mozilla-something, I borrowed the value from a browser.